# uncaught referenceError: invalid left-hand side

Tags: javascript, events

I keep getting an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment". The code is supposed to expand an image when it is clicked (which works). The next part is that when the mouse enters the picture there is supposed to be a border added. This is the part that causes an error and doesn't work. I'm very new to events so i'm really unsure how to proceed with this. If I could get the border to show up onmouseover that would be great.

```
<style>
    .image {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;
    border-color:black;
    }   
</style>

<img src='image0.jpg' id='pic0' class='image'></img>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    pic0.onclick = mouseOver0;
    pic0.onmousemove = mouseFocus0;

function mouseOver0() {
    document.getElementById('pic0').style.width="200px";
    document.getElementById('pic0').style.height="200px";
    }   

function mouseFocus0() {
    pic0.style.border-width="3px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use element IDs as global variables, it's considered a very bad feature. Use *getElementById* or *querySelector* to get references to elements by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is The Subtraction Operator.

You are saying assign to string `"200px"` to "`pic0.style.border` minus `width`", which doesn't make sense.

You can't have a `-` in an identifier in JavaScript.

CSS property names are converted to their camelCase equivalent: `borderWidth`